# Azure AD get users by criteria gives empty result when the value contains '/'

Tags: url, azure

I am trying to use the graph api call and fetch users from Azure AD by odata filter condition. I am able to do it successfully as long as their is no "/" character value of the search parameter. If their is a "/" it is returning empty response.
For eg:

URL: https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users?$filter=extension_abdc_Id eq 'abc'&api-version=1.5

gives users whose id is abc.

But the below URL:

URL: https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users?$filter=extension_abdc_Id eq 'ab/c'&api-version=1.5

gives empty response although their is a user with id = "ab/c"

Is this special not allowed as a search parameter? If so what are the other special characters that are not allowed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to URLEncode the '/' character? So ab/c becomes ab%2Fc

Comment: Thanks Matt, url encoded value works now.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer I posted below so I can get some points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to URLEncode the '/' character in your query string.

So `ab/c` will become `ab%2Fc`